# Broadcast not triggered when using bluetoothLEScanner().startScan

Tags: android, beacon, altbeacon, google-beacon-platform

Im trying to wake my application when the device enters a region of beacons with a specific UUID.

So far I tried using the native 
[BluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner), providing a PendingIntent to launch a Broadcast reciever.

I also tried [RxBleClient](http://polidea.github.io/RxAndroidBle/) which is an amazing library which does work when doing a regular discovery.

I tried [AltBeacon](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) lib which is also a very thorough and brilliant lib.

I also tried play services Nearby Apis.

But all failed. They can all scan for beacons regularly but when trying to basically, register and let the device scan while in the bg. The broadcast never gets triggered.

I also tried all 4 while using a foreground service. That did not help either. 
Ill also mention this is all done on Android 8. 
I went over the code in both libs and they both eventually use the same function call from the native bluetoothadapter. So Im assuming if that fails, everything else will fail too. 
Ill also mention that when supplying the startScan function with a CallBack instead of a PendingIntent, the callback is constantly triggered for all scanned BT devices. If I add a ScanFilter to filter for my UUID only, it fails. 
What am I missing?

Btw, when I implemented this in Ios, it worked flawlessly. The app is awoken as if I used a Geofence enter/exit trigger.

Why wont this work in Android??
Any thoughts?

EDIT:
This is how I used the code from the AltBeacon library. It is basically a copy paste from the DOCS tutorial. Only difference is I encapsulated it in a seperate class:

```
public void init(AppCompatActivity context) {
    if (isRegistered) {
        return;
    }

    BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    if (bluetoothManager != null) {
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            context.startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1002);
        } else {
            register(context);
        }
    }
}

public void register(AppCompatActivity context) {

    if (isRegistered) {
        return;
    }

    executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Region region = new Region("com.sample.WakeOnDiscovery", Identifier.parse("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"), Identifier.fromInt(11180), null);
            bootstrapRegion = new RegionBootstrap(new BootstrapNotifier() {
                @Override
                public Context getApplicationContext() {
                    return Application.getContextFromApplicationClass();
                }

                @Override
                public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                    Logger.log(TAG, "didEnterRegion: " + region.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                    Logger.log(TAG, "didExitRegion: " + region.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
                    Logger.log(TAG, "didDetermineStateForRegion: " + region.toString() + "|" + i);
                }
            }, region);
        }
    });

    isRegistered = true;
}
```

This is when I try to scan for this specific UUID and major int (and without the major int). Only the didDetermineStateForRegion is triggered once I think. With int i = 0 or 1.

Regarding the UUID I tried 2 different UUIDs. The first is one that I generate in a sample app I wrote in IOS. The ios app advertises itself as a beacon. I can see it in a different app that uses a regular discovery function.
But the onEnterRegion does not trigger.

I also tried a UUID from an iBeacon device that I use regularly for years now.
Still no dice.

When I try using the native android ble scanner I use this:

```
ScanSettings settings = (new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)).setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES).build();
    List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>(); // Make a scan filter matching the beacons I care about
    filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder()/*.setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"))*/.build());
    bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters, settings, getPendingIntent(context));
```

and:

```
private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context) {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, BTDiscoveryBroadcast.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

I tried passing null as filters, I tried an empty array list and I tried an actual filter with the same UUID.

Still nothing works.

what I did see by chance in logcat is this error message:

```
E/NearbyDirect: Could not start scan. [CONTEXT service_id=49 ]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Receiver com.google.location.nearby.direct.bluetooth.state.FastPairScanner$4@535d6ea registered with differing handler (was Handler (adxv) {8fab16a} now Handler (android.app.ActivityThread$H) {e4e0078})
```

I think this occurs when using the AltBeacon lib as well. I can only assume this is related to my problem.

**EDIT 2:**
I tried this:

```
ScanSettings settings = (new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)).setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES).build();
            List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>(); // Make a scan filter matching the beacons I care about
            byte[] manufacturerData = new byte[] {
                    // iBeacon identifier prefix
                    0x02, 0x15,
                    // Your Proximity UUID
                    (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xC5, 0x6D, (byte) 0xB5, (byte) 0xDF, (byte) 0xFB, 0x48, (byte) 0xD2, (byte) 0xB0, 0x60, (byte) 0xD0, (byte) 0xF5, (byte) 0xA7, 0x10, (byte) 0x96, (byte) 0xE0,
                        0x3, 0x20, 0x3, 0x20, (byte) 0xC5
            };
            int manufacturerId = 0x004c; // Apple
            filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setManufacturerData(manufacturerId, manufacturerData).build());
            bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters, settings, getPendingIntent(context));
```

The bytes data I retrieved after doing a regular .startDiscovery scan, locating my bt device and extracting from ScanResult the data. Just to make sure its precisely the same.

Still does not trigger broadcast :(

Comment: The problem may be with your ScanFilter.  Please show your code  I wrote the implementation in the Android Beacon Library, which always uses scan filters with this intent-backed scan.  I can confirm it does work and is similarly reliable to iOS if you set up your scan filters properly.

Comment: @davidgyoung Hi David, first of all allow me to thank you for your amazing AltBeacon lib. We've been using it for years and its amazing! Does the job and does it well. I edited my OP with code. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you need to take a step back before you can address this.  What DOES WORK?  Can you ever detect your beacon in any circumstances with your code?  Are you sure you know your beacon identifier?  Is there something else fundamental wrong like lack of bluetooth or location permissions?

Comment: Permissions are granted. Bluetooth is enabled. There are 2 approaches that work. First, when I simply call bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(). With that the broadcast receiver gets triggered and I see all the devices that were scanned. But this is not a background scan. I can simply call that with intervals and scan from time to time. This is not what I am looking for. The second approach that works is providing the getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan call with a callback instead of a pending intent. The issue here is when adding a filter. The callback stops. Although the identifier is correct.

Comment: Something is fundamentally wrong here.  The startDiscovery call is a Bluetooth classic operation.  It should not directly affect BLE scanning.  The fact that it suddenly causes you to get BLE scan results suggests it  is unblocking something as a side effect.  Perhaps your code is somehow  blocking the threads Android uses to send BLE intent callbacks, and doing a startDiscovery somehow resets Bluetooth to unblock these threads.

Comment: I am not sure if its related but perhaps the illigalstate exception I saw (stated in OP) could be related some how?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set up a scan filter to look for a beacon UUID, **code like this won't work:**

```
filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString("E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0")).build());
```

The above code will set a filter to look for a BLE device advertising a GATT Service UUID matching E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0.  A GATT Service UUID has absolutely nothing to do with a Bluetooth Beacon Proximity UUID, even though both UUIDs may look superficially the same.  In other words, you are telling the filter to look for a connectable bluetooth device that advertises a custom service that just happens to be the same as your beacon identifier.  This will never find anything, because such a device is almost guaranteed not to exist.

What you want to do instead is more complicated -- you want to set up a scan filter that looks for a bluetooth LE manufacturer advertisement (which iBeacon and AltBeacon advertisements are), that have a specific manufacturer code and start with a certain sequence of bytes.

Getting the exact byte sequence for the filter is tricky because it depends on both the manufacturer ID the beacon layout (iBeacon or AltBeacon).  This is one of the many complexities the Android Beacon Library handles for you.

If you really need to do it yourself you would do something like this for iBeacon (WARNING: untested code):

```
byte[] manufacturerData = new byte[] {
            // iBeacon identifier prefix
            0x02, 0x15, 
            // Your Proximity UUID
            0xE2, 0xC5, 0x6D, 0xB5, 0xDF, 0xFB, 0x48, 0xD2, 0xB0, 0x60, 0xD0, 0xF5, 0xA7, 0x10, 0x96, 0xE0
            };
int manufacturerId = 0x004c; // Apple
ScanFilter filter =
filters.add(new ScanFilter.Buider().setManufacturerData(manufacturerId, manufacturerData).build());
```

Comment: I will try this out right now. But it still does not answer why when NOT providing any filter, the broadcast is not getting triggered on ANY kind of bt discovery.
As I mentioned, I tried scanning without providing any filter. Only scan settings a pending intent and that's it. And I have many beacons and bt devices near me. Still no broadcast triggered... I would expect that when not providing a filter, any bt advertisement would trigger the broadcast. Wouldn't it?

Comment: The intent-backed API is designed to work with a filter, otherwise it would be too taxing on the operating system to send every single bluetooth packet detection via intent.  I suspect it does not even work if you don't provide a filter, although you'd have to check the docs or the Android source to confirm.

Comment: I tried a .startDiscovery scan. Found the bt device I was looking for, extracted its manufacturer data (bytes) and used that as a filter. (shown in last edit)... It still did not work. I also think I am missing something. But really cant see what it is. The code is really simple. It should be working! lol :)

Comment: At the end we decided to initiate a scan ourselves using RxBleClient and then parse the device byte data using your BeaconParser (from AltBeacon) and check its UUID. The scan is being performed in intervals (remote parameter).